# How do you change the location that Maven reads Cucumber feature files?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, gherkin

I have a large number of feature files right now and I am trying to categorize the features with folders inside resources. When I do this I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory:

It then proceeds to display the directory going to the resources package.

I have tried changing the path through the cucumber options in the runner, however I am running the features files as cucumber features and It appears to just disregard all the options from the runner.

Comment: How's your feature file and runner files are look ?

Comment: The feature file is fine. I think the problem may be with the runner. I am guessing it has to do with the @Cucumber.Options vs CucumberOptions. Im going to see if I am using an outdated cucumber version

Comment: Well, I was using an older version of cucumber (1.1.2) and I updated to 1.2.4. The CucumberOptions works now, however it still won't let me change the location, or at least it doesn't work. Here is my runner. 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  tags = {"pretty", "json:target/json/output.json", "html:target/html/"}, 
  features = "/BBAutomation/src/test/resources/features/"
  )
public class RunnerTest 
{
 
}

Comment: Not gluing. It actually works when i run the runner. What doesn't work is when I right click on a feature file and click run as... feature. If I pop it right back into resources, it works

Comment: right clicking on feature file will never work. It works only when you execute from runner file.

Comment: I got it fixed. It was an IDE issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason, the IDE wouldn't actually refactor the location of the feature files when I moved them, however I was able to fix this problem by creating new feature files in the desired folder and just copy/paste the content over. Problem solved.